# Trouble installing ATG 10.1

Tags: atg, atg-dynamo

Past two days, I was trying to install ATG in my windows machine using the ATG Installation and Configuration Guide.

I am able to install,

1. Oracle ATG Web Commerce platform
2. Oracle ATG Web Commerce Search

Then before installing CIM, I tried to configure the database. I am using MySQL 5.6.13.

In the section Creating Database Tables for ATG Portal, they asked to run the following command to run the script

```
      install-mysql userid password database
```

but in the above command, what database name I should give?

Please guide me on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are installing the Commerce Reference Store (CRS) you can use the following:

`crsprod`

as specified on page 9 of the CRS [installation guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24152_01/CRS.10-1/ATGCRSInstall/ATGCRSInstall.pdf)

If you are not using CRS, you can use whatever name you want since you then need to configure it in your DataSource files.